# Wp Query with multiple custom tag(taxonomy) by get the terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I need to do a wp query that will get any post in custom post type that has one custom taxonomy (not hierarchical, like a post tag) or more. My current code work for one tag, but I've try for multiple  and I can't do...
I've try a lot of possibilites, query by taxonomy ID etc, no one works for me.
Can you help me ? Thank's !

There is my actual code, work for one tag :

```
<?php foreach (get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tag_blogcom' ) as $term ) {}?>

<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'blogcom',
'tag_blogcom' => $term->slug,
'showposts' => 10
));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tag_blogcom' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $slugs[] = $term->slug;
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type' => 'blogcom',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'tag_blogcom',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => $slugs,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                            'posts_per_page' => 10
                            )
                        );
```

Check the Taxonomy Parameters at [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: Obviously... I'ts working, but i've try earlier by putting everything in the same <?php ?>. In this case, this send me a warning : invalid argument for foreach, I need to make the get the terms and foreach in another <?php ?> in the top of my file. Thank's

Comment: @Newo1t, if it's working, please accept it as the answer to help people to find it easily.